# Delete null values on multiple worksheets and export to excel

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I am trying to write a code that deletes null values on multiple excel sheets on specific columns and export the file. Any help is appreciated!

Code below:

import pandas as pd

```
fileName = 'data.xls'
df = pd.ExcelFile(fileName)
arrayOf_SheetNames = df.sheet_names

for sheetName in arrayOf_SheetNames:
   masterdf = pd.read_excel(fileName, sheet_name=sheetName, header=4)
   masterdf = masterdf.dropna(subset=['Column 1', 'Column 2'], inplace=True)

masterdf.to_excel('file_path.xls')
```

Comment: You're trying to delete the null values (like, replace them with zeros or something?) or you want to drop rows that have null values?

Comment: @user1717828 I'm trying to drop rows with null values

Answer (score 0):

One problem you're having is you are redefining what `masterdf` is for every sheet in the for loop.  Another problem is you aren't saving it at the end with `writer.save()`.

```
dfs = pd.read_excel('/tmp/Untitled spreadsheet-2.xlsx', sheet_name=None, header=4)
writer = pd.ExcelWriter('/tmp/out.xlsx')
for sheetname, df in dfs.items():                                                                 
    df.dropna(subset=['Column 1', 'Column 2'], inplace=True)
    df.to_excel(writer, sheetname, index=False)
writer.save()
```